# Remove gap between next column in a flex list

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have created a list that has 2 columns. But there is a gab between the content. How can I remove this? I have created a fiddle to illustrate my problem: https://jsfiddle.net/tk83w1L4/

I have tried with `flex-wrap: wrap;` and `flex-direction: column;` and `align-content: flex-start;` none works

```
.wrapper {
    columns: 2;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    li {
        display: flex;
        background-color: #f0f0f0;

        &:hover {
            background-color: red;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: padding:0 margin:0 for the ul

Comment: @TemaniAfif thanks, but i'd like to have some padding on the list..

Comment: so what is the gap you are talking about then?

Comment: @TemaniAfif hover over List 7 on this fiddle, and you see the red background going to the next column: https://jsfiddle.net/2ec4o5q7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `inline-flex` instead of `flex` there is known issues when using block level elements but using the inline equivalent fixes the issue

```css
.wrapper {
  /*flex-wrap: wrap; not needed*/
  border: 1px solid #000;
  columns: 2;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline-flex;
  min-width: 100%; /* to make it behave as flex */
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  padding: 5px;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li>List 1</li>
    <li>List 2</li>
    <li>List 3</li>
    <li>List 4</li>
    <li>List 5</li>
    <li>List 6</li>
    <li>List 7</li>
    <li>List 8</li>
    <li>List 9</li>
    <li>List 10</li>
    <li>List 11</li>
    <li>List 12</li>
    <li>List 113</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

By the way you don't really need flexbox here:

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  columns: 2;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 100%; 
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  padding: 5px;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li>List 1</li>
    <li>List 2</li>
    <li>List 3</li>
    <li>List 4</li>
    <li>List 5</li>
    <li>List 6</li>
    <li>List 7</li>
    <li>List 8</li>
    <li>List 9</li>
    <li>List 10</li>
    <li>List 11</li>
    <li>List 12</li>
    <li>List 113</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your css to fix the issue

```
.wrapper {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    ul {
      columns: 2;
    }
    li {
          display: flex;
          background-color: #f0f0f0;

          &:hover {
            background-color: red;
          }
    }
}
```